# Implementing a TCP client in Golang

Tags: go, tcp

I am very new to concurrent programming in general and want to know if my implementation is thread-safe.

I'm currently working on implementing a TCP client in golang. The service listens on a port and accepts HTTP requests. On a parallel, the service also establishes a connection to an outside TCP server to which it will send binary data.

While I got this to work, I'm unsure if this is the correct approach or should I be adding something more.

The sequence of steps is this

I start my webserver which first tries to establish a connection with a TCP server. On a successful connection, I start listening for incoming HTTP requests

*note*: Successful connection to the TCP server involves me sending a `login` packet to this TCP server which authenticates me

```
type TCPconnector struct {
    Conn                    net.Conn
    DataChannel             chan []byte
    reconnectAttempt        int
    reconnectMaxRetries     int
    reconnectMaxDelay       time.Duration
    autoReconnect           bool
    lastOrderSent           time.Time
}

const addr string = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
const defaultReconnectMaxAttempts int = 10
const defaultReconnectMaxDelay time.Duration = 60000 * time.Millisecond    

func NewTCPConnector() (*TCPconnector, error) {

    dataChannel := make(chan []byte)

    return &TCPconnector{
      DataChannel:         dataChannel,
      reconnectMaxDelay:   defaultReconnectMaxDelay,
      reconnectMaxRetries: defaultReconnectMaxAttempts,
      reconnectAttempt:    0,
      autoReconnect:       true,
    }, nil
}

func Server() {
    TCPconnector, err := NewTCPConnector()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }

    err = TCPconnector.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }

    defer TCPconnector.Conn.Close()

    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Post("/placeOrder", PlaceOrder(TCPconnector))

    err = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

The connect method tries to establish a connection to the TCP server and responsible to spawning goroutines responsible for writing packets, sending heartbeat packets and reading responses from the server.

```
  func (t *TcpConnector) Connect() {
    for {

        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
        defer cancel()

        if t.reconnectAttempt > t.reconnectMaxRetries {
            t.onNoReconnect(t.reconnectAttempt)
            return
        }

        if t.reconnectAttempt > 0 {
            t.onReconnect()
        }

        c, err := net.Dial("tcp", t.Url)

        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Connection to tcp server failed with error : %+v", err)

            if t.autoReconnect {
                t.reconnectAttempt++
                continue
            }

            return
        }

        t.Log.Infof("Connection established @ %s", time.Now())
        t.Conn = c

        defer t.Conn.Close()

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        wg.Add(1)

        go t.SendHeartbeat(ctx)
        go t.Write(&wg, cancel)
        go t.RecieveResponse()

        err = t.SendLoginPacket()

        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

The sendLoginPacket is pretty straightforward, we form the packet and sends it across the DataChannel which is then picked up by the Write goroutine

```
func (t *TcpConnector) SendLoginPacket() error {
    loginRequestBody := dto.LoginRequest{
        VersionNo: 24,
    }

    finalPacketToBeSent, err := t.getFinalPacketToBeSent(1, loginRequestBody)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t.DataChannel <- finalPacketToBeSentToMOSL
    return nil
}
```

The Write() goroutine works like this

```
func (t *TcpConnector) Write(wg *sync.WaitGroup, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-t.DataChannel:
            _, err := t.Conn.Write(data)
            if err != nil {
                t.Conn.Close()
                wg.Done()
                cancel()
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Recieve` goroutine is also a straightforward loop that returns on any error

```
func (t *TcpConnector) RecieveResponse() {
    for {

        // Get the first 45 bytes of the response and check the messageLength for the remaining length of the message
        headerBuff := make([]byte, 45)

        _, err := t.Conn.Read(headerBuff)
        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Couldnt read tcp header response from MOSL : %+v ", err)
            return
        }
        headerResponse := dto.MessageHeader{}
        err = binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(headerBuff), binary.LittleEndian, &headerResponse)
        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Couldnt convert bytes header to struct : %+v ", err)
            return
        }

        // Get remaining bytes from server and decrypt it (remaining bytes = messageLength - 45 bytes for the header)
        bodyBuff := make([]byte, headerResponse.MessageLength-45)

        _, err = t.Conn.Read(bodyBuff)
        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Couldnt read tcp body response from MOSL : %+v ", err)
            return
        }

        decryptedResponseBody, err := DecryptAESCFB(bodyBuff, t.Key, t.IV)
        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Couldnt decrypt body response from MOSL : %+v ", err)
            return
        }
        go t.handleMOSLResponse(headerResponse, decryptedResponseBody)
    }
}
```

And lastly, the heartbeat request which is fired every 30 seconds to the TCP server

```
func (t *TcpConnector) SendHeartbeat(ctx context.Context) {

    ticker := time.NewTicker(30 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case x := <-ticker.C:
            messageHeader, err := getMessageHeaderInBytes(129, 0, 0, t.AppState.Config.Username)
            if err != nil {
                t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Error Converting heartbeat request data to bytes: %+v, with seconds: %s", err, x)
                return
            }
            t.DataChannel <- messageHeader

        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Exiting hearbeat goroutine")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

My main concern over this implementation is if i'm handling the error cases well?

1. Are my goroutines being shutdown properly in case the TCP server closes the connection?
2. Is there a better way to start and stop the goroutines?